# HTML: Page width increases when body content is larger than page

Tags: html, css, scroll, height, width

The problem I'm getting is that I have two pages, a page that has content greater than the height of the page (the page that you would have to scroll down), and another page that has lesser content than the height of the page.

On the page that scrolls down the width of the page (header, footer and body included) increases by 1px. But on the page that doesn't scroll down, this doesn't happen.

Here's the code for the page that scrolls down:

```css
html, body {
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 0.7s opacity;
}

body.fade-out {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: none;
}

a {
  color: black;
}

.Menu, .Menu ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 25%;
}

.Menu li {
  width: 15em;
}

.Menu li ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -999em;
}

.Menu li:hover ul {
  left: auto;
}

.Menu li:hover ul, .Menu li.sfhover ul {
  left: auto;
  background-color: green;
}

.Menu a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.Menu a:hover {
  background-color: #dcefdc;
}

.Menu div a {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.Menu div a:hover {
  height: 50px;
}

#container {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#header {
  border-top:3px solid #242729;
  align-content: center;
  background-color: #5f5f5f;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  font-family: TheLightFont;
  font-size: 37px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: #555555;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

#divmen {   
 font-family: TheLightFont;
 font-size: 150%;
}

#logo {
  align-content: center;
}

#Title {
  width: 100%;
}

#body {
  padding: 0.1px;
  padding-bottom: 60px; /* Height of the footer */
}

#divcon {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 37%;
  margin-top: 6em;
  font-family: TheLightFont;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

#footer {
  background-color: #242729;
  width: 100%;
  height: 110px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  font-family: Hangar;
}

/*----------fonts----------*/

@font-face { 
  font-family: TheLightFont; 
  src: url('TheLightFont.ttf');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Hangar;
  src: url('HANGAR_flat.ttf');
}

.Menu { 
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.Menu div a.current{
  height: 50px;
}

.Menu a.current {
  background-color: #242729;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header"><!-content here-></div>
  <div id="body">
    <div id="divmen"><!-content here-></div>
    <div id="divcon"><!-content here-></div>
  </div>
  <div id=footer><!-content here-></div>
</div>
```

The code for the page without the scroll is the same, but with less content in `<divcon>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing my code I came upon where the issue was, after changing the
`.Menu li` value for the width it was able to fix the problem.